# Running bathroom vent duct through cold air return

Tags: code-compliance, ventilation, ducts, remodeling

I am remodelling a basement and I noticed that the old bathroom has the vent duct  running through the cold air return ( for about 6ft, in and out, the entrance and exit are sealed) and then outside. Is that ok, or should I try to reroute the duct around the cold air return (which might not be an easy task). I am in Canada, in case regulations are different.

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt it's a code/regulations concern. Return ducts (at least in the U.S.) are often simply framing cavities. The bigger question is whether it substantially blocks return airflow.

Comment: It does not look to me that this would be an issue, there seems to be plenty of space for air to flow, even with the duct inside.

Comment: If there was the potential for noxious gas to enter the HVAC system, that would be a code/safety issue and I'd fix it. as it is, I'd leave it alone.